# Keyboard shortcut for add reference to project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the keyboard shortcut for adding a reference to a project in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 9):

There is no default shortcut for this however you can add one yourself:

1. Click Tools -> Options
2. Select "Keyboard" from the list on the left
3. In show commands type: `Project.AddReference`
4. Select the add reference command, click into the "Press shortcut keys" box and pick your own shortcut.

I'd suggest something like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> as the CAS combo tendss to have very little overlap.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>  shows the menu then select the required reference to add

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard

You can search all of the keyboard shortcuts and reassign them if you want to.

Project.AddReference appears to be unset out of the box, but you can set your own.

Answer (score 0):

Important [Keyboard shortcut](http://rajeshrolen.blogspot.com/2009/08/visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts.html) of Visual Studio